# Why the Code/Logic is working differently for different ranges?

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, logic

I wrote the code for problem 4 of Project Euler--
it works perfectly for the range (10,100)--
case1--

```
for i in range(10,100):
    for j in range(10,100):
        a = i*j
        b = str(a)
        d = str(a)[::-1]
        if b == d:
            c = b
            p1 = i
            p2 = j
print(f"{c} is palindrome ")
```

but for range (100,1000)
case2---

```
for i in range(100,1000):
    for j in range(100,1000):       
        a = i*j
        b = str(a)
        d = str(a)[::-1]
        if b == d:
            c = b
            p1 = i
            p2 = j    
print(f"{c} is palindrome ")
```

the output is wrong
WHY??
Why the code works differently ??
For case1 it gives the correct output. But as the range changes it provides wrong output.

Comment: Please post a [mre].  Wrap your function in a function that takes the two ranges and c as arguments. p1 and p2 does not appear to be used.  What data do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: Because you find a smaller palindrome and assign it to `c` after you have found the largest. You need to add a check so that you only store the largest palindrome found

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your logic, if any palindrome is found it automatically assigns to `c` without checking it is greater than to `c`.
for example when `i=993` and `j =913` then `c= 906609` but this value replace by 580085 when `i =995` and `j = 583`. So you cannot get expected output.

first, try, I provided the sample code below. Look at only if you didn't get the idea.

```
c=0
for i in range(100,1000):
    for j in range(100,1000):       
        a = i*j
        b = str(a)
        d = str(a)[::-1]
        if b == d:

            if a>c:
                c=a

            p1 = i
            p2 = j    
print(f"{c} is palindrome ")
```